# Bi-infinite geodesic in geodesic Gromov-Hyperbolic spaces

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, geodesic, metric-geometry, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

For a geodesic Gromov Hyperbolic metric space X is it true that there exists $C>0$ such that any two bi-infinite geodesic with same end points at boundary stays within $C$-neighbouhood of each other?

I know that geodesic rays going to same point in the boundary stays within a constant distance of each other after a finite time .

But I could not find an argument for to prove the prior statement, neither was I able to show find a counter example.

I shall be grateful if someone could comment on or help me in this regard .

Comment: Hint: use the slim quadrilateral property. Your $C$ will be $2\delta$.

Comment: Thanks @MoisheKohan I got it .. thank you for the help .